# ios swift UILabel font size is not change programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I want to change font size of UILabel but it not changing programatically.
when i'm changing text color it change color

I was try many things but not working

following is my code

```
@IBOutlet weak var lblExample: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.lblExample.font = UIFont(name: self.lblExample.font.fontName, size: 40)
        //self.lblExample.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40)
        //self.lblExample.font = UIFont(name: "System", size: 40)
        //self.lblExample.font = self.lblExample.font.withSize(40);

        self.lblExample.textColor = UIColor.green
    }
```

Attribute Inspector Property

[image]

> How to change font of UILabel
>   why is it not changing

Comment: Your code looks good, please make sure you didn't check that text would shrink if it doesn't fit on your storyboard's attribute inspector. Or simply make the label's rect bigger and try again.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the attribute inspector linked to your label.

Comment: Issue solved:- I was set variant font in **Attribute Inspector Property** so font size not update after remove variant font all codes are working properly.

Answer (score 1):

And it's not changed?

```
let lab = UILabel(frame: ...)
lab.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Fett", size: 14)
lab.font = lab.font
lab.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
lab.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .bold)
lab.text = "TEST"
```